# statsmodel.api fit() throws overflow error

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels, mnist, hessian-matrix

I am using Logistic regression for Mnist digit classification and am using statsmodel.api library to fit the parameters but the Logit.fit() still throws an overflow warning.Below is the error I am getting on Windows10,python 2.7 using library downloaded from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py:1213: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp   return 1/(1+np.exp(-X)) C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py:1263: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log   return np.sum(np.log(self.cdf(q*np.dot(X,params)))) Warning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
         Current function value: inf
         Iterations: 35 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "code.py", line 44, in <module>
    result1 = logit1.fit()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py", line 1376, in fit
    disp=disp, callback=callback, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py", line 203, in fit
    disp=disp, callback=callback, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 434, in fit
    Hinv = np.linalg.inv(-retvals['Hessian']) / nobs   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 526, in inv
    ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 90, in _raise_linalgerror_singular
    raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix") numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Comment: Please, provide your code and data. (See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )

Comment: The problem is not an overflow, but a "singular matrix", please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105154/calculate-logistic-regression-in-python

Answer (score 0):

It is because the input matrix is a singular matrix during the logistic modelling computation, hence, you have the `LinAlgError`. If you apply some regularisation to that input, it will works fine. An example is to use 'l1' as in [Stat models](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.fit_regularized.html), or 'l2' as the default option in [Logistic Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression) model of sklearn.